Encrypted media error in media3 exoplayer
i am trying to play encrypted mp4 file in media3 exoplayer v1.3.1 but I am getting this error:
Playback error
androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:717)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:687)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:223)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:324)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor, PngExtractor, WebpExtractor, BmpExtractor, HeifExtractor) could read the stream.{contentIsMalformed=false, dataType=1}
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:94)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1044)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:421)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

When I try to decrypt the file into file manager it works perfectly fine but it does not work in exoplayer. Here is the code I am using to play media in exoplayer:
https://github.com/WeMakeBest/Encrypted-Video-Player-Code/tree/main
Expected result:
It should be playing in exoplayer.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
